# Using multiversion view trigger to maintain unique ID in ArcSDE for Oracle?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, enterprise-geodatabase, oracle-dbms, trigger

I'm trying to identify the best way to automatically maintain a unique id column in Oracle ArcSDE.  I don't want to use a class extension, since I've multiple third party users of the data and it's too much of a headache.  I thought I was being clever by editing the insert trigger created by the creation of a multiversion view for the feature class.

I created a sequence in Oracle, and then tried to use sequenceName.NEXTVAL to insert that into the appropriate column.  The trigger compiles fine, and I can edit the feature class and insert new features just fine, but my sequence value is not getting inserted into the row.  For example, I wrote

```
addNextVal := address_seq.nextval;
INSERT INTO SDE.A746 VALUES (next_rowid, addNextVal,:new.SUITE, ...
```

but it didn't work.

Any thoughts on the approach, and what I might do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You put sequence value into `:new.address_id` (use the correct column name instead of `address_id`) and let the insert command do its work:

```
create trigger A746_insert_trigger
before insert on SDE.A746
for each row
begin
    select address_seq.nextval into :new.address_id from dual;
end;
/
```

Comment: your code is not complete so maybe you need something different.

[Example1](http://jen.fluxcapacitor.net/geek/autoincr.html), [Example2](http://www.razorsql.com/features/oracle_add_sequence_trigger.html)